# How to validate optional query parameters in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

So I have a routes file that looks something like this:

```
GET     /myRes                 controllers.MyController.get(ids: Option[String], elems: Option[String])
```

All well and good. Users can get stuff by doing:

```
/myRes
/myRes?ids=X
/myRes?elems=Y
/myRes?ids=X&elems=Y
```

However, they can also query the interface by doing:

```
/myRes?id=X
```

Which is problematic, because in this case the user is gets the same result as if they had queried `/myRes`, which is almost certainly not the result they expected. This has been causing a lot of confusion/bugs for developers of the API. Is there an elegant way to catch incorrect/unspecified query parameters being passed to the controller and return a hard error for such queries?

Edit: Changed title to something more descriptive. My problem is basically validating the query parameters to catch any query parameters passed to the API which are not valid/correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the help of a macro annotation like the following one:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly
import play.api.mvc._

@compileTimeOnly("respond 400 bad request in case of unexpected params")
class StrictParams extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro StrictParamsMacro.impl
}

object StrictParamsMacro {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case q"def $name(..$params) = $action { ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        val supportedParamNames = params.map(ab => ab.name.toString).toSet
        c.Expr[Any](
          q"""def $name(..$params) = { req: Request[_] =>
            val unsupportedParams = req.queryString.keySet -- $supportedParamNames
            if (unsupportedParams.nonEmpty) {
              BadRequest(unsupportedParams.mkString("Unsupported Params: ", ", ", ""))
            } else {
              $body
            }
          }"""
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can annotate your action method like this:

```
@StrictParams
def get(ids: Option[String], elems: Option[String]) = Action {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Will try this ASAP.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. When we try this, we get a "[error] /*/app/controllers/MyController.scala:88: respond 400 bad request in case of unexpected params" in the compile step. Are we missing something?

Comment: Macro paradise is required to compile. Add the following setting to your projects - both the macro lib and projects using it. ```addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Still doesn't work unfortunately; getting an exception during macro expansion. Thinking this might be because we are also using Swagger annotations, but even commenting out those results in further issues with the compilation. Will have to try and dig a bit into the generated code and see if we can figure out what is wrong - alternatively just do it without the macro, I guess.

Comment: Multiple errors. With the swagger annotations removed, though, the relevant one is probable noting in the routes file: "Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.Request[_] => Product with java.io.Serializable as a Handler for requests".

Answer (score 0):

i usually pass it like this on get method

```
GET    /getSomething        Controllers.Application.getData()

GET    /getSomething/:id         Controllers.Application.getData(id:Integer)

GET    /getSomething/:id/:name          Controllers.Application.getData(id:Integer, name :String)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that's essentially the same as setting required parameters. That works for query parameters as well, but not is not what I'm trying to do. None of the query parameters are required, and I do not want to specify every possible combination of query parameters - that is not really scalable beyond 2-3 params.

Comment: I changed the title to hopefully make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `QueryStringBindable[A]` to bind a `Map` of query string parameters to an instance of type `A`.
See [the corresponding documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRequestBinders#querystringbindable).
Didn't fully explore it yet, but it doesn't seem too difficult to implement a `QueryStringBindable[Option[A]]`.

If you want to forbid confusing parameters (e.g. allowing `ids` but not `id`), you can check for unexpected keys in the parameters `Map` and return an error message if needed (although I would recommand to accept the `id` key to match the behaviour expected by users).